# Django - Join two table in view and use it in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm using python 3.4.5 with Diango 2.0.2

I have 2 tables with a foreign key. For some reasons, I need to use 2 tables to store these data.

I want to generate a table which contain the following information.

program.name , program.program_id , program.filter(user=request.user.id).status(if exist, if not exist, keep it NULL)

models.py

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    program_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class ProgramInfo(models.Model):
    pid = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=1003)
```

views.py

```
def program_list(request):
    program = Program.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'panel/program_list.html', {'program': program})
```

template

```
{% for prog in program %}
<tr>
    <td> {{ prog.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ prog.program_id }} </td>
    <td> {{ "program's status of existing user" }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How to generate a table which contain the following information?

program.name , program.program_id , program.filter(user=request.user.id).status

I have 2 solutions,

(1) generate a table and pass it to template

(2) send the program table to template, and use something like program.filter(user=request.user.id).status in "td"

But I don't know how to do it for these 2 solutions.

The table should be like this

```
NameA, 123, yes
NameB, 234, 
NameC, 345, no
NameD, 456, 
NameE, 567, no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgramInfo has a ForeignKey field pointing to a Program instance

```
pid = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Thus, you can have multiple ProgramInfo instances linked to a single Program instance. To retrieve that list, simply use:

```
program_instance = Program.objects.get(id=123)
# gives you the list of ProgramInfo instances:
programinfo_list = program_instance.programinfo_set
```

You can find more information about [Many to One relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) in Django doc. FYI, instance.programinfo_set is a [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/) (a child class of the more generic [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/)). Thus, it provides an interface to lookup instances contained in this relationship.

If you need to have only 1 to 1 relationship between your models, use a OneToOne field instead:

```
pid = models.OneToOneField(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it's not OneToOne relateionship, Actually, not all "program" has data in  "program_info". I added a sample of table in the original question.

Comment: I have try to use {{ prog.programpublisher_set.count }} in the template. It can count it.(better than before), but, how to get the status with the user_id? can use something like this? {{ prog.programpublisher_set.filter(user_id=request.user.id).count }}

Comment: I added links to corresponding Django docs pages. It will explain everything you need to know for your issue. Unfortunately, I can't explain the whole relationship management in Django. You should try to think your data as objects instead of tables, it will be easier to manipulate it with Django ORM.